# How to Successfully Type a Function that injects a key and returns the input type with one extra key?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Given we have:

```js
type Bid = {
  status: 'CONFIRMED' | 'UNPAID';
  amountInBtc: number;
}
```

how do I type a function that takes in a `Bid` with or without `status`, requiring `amountInBtc` and returning the correct type (that is, `status` is NOT optional if the input had a `status` and is `undefined` is there was no `status` passed in.

## What I Tried and (Mis)Understand

In the end, I tried something like:

```js
import type { O } from 'ts-toolbelt';

const polyfillBidWithAmount = <T extends O.Required<Partial<Bid>, 'amountInBtc'>>(
  bid: T
) => {
  return { ...bid, amount: bitcoinToSatoshis(bid.amountInBtc) } as const;
};
```

but it returns `amount` and `amountInBtc` as definitely there and everything else (`status` in our example) as optional, no matter what the input bid is (no matter whether `status` is set or not), and I cannot understand why.

Answer (score 0):

[Optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) are expressed in Typescript using `?`:

```
type Bid = {
  status?: 'CONFIRMED' | 'UNPAID';
  ...
}
```

If we attempt to access `status` where it has not been initialised, we will get `undefined`. Likewise if we attempt to access any of its the properties on `status` using [optional chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining):

```
const b: Bid = { amountInBtc: 5 };
console.log(b.status) // returns undefined
console.log(b.status?.length) // returns undefined
```

This way, `status` defaults to `undefined`, so you can simply use `Bid` as your return type from `polyfillBidWithAmount`.

I couldn't quite suss out if this was part of your question, but as far as making `status` **required** in the return type goes, I have two suggestions:

**Approach 1: Make `status` concrete in the return type**

```
function polyfillBidWithAmount(b: Bid) : Bid & { status: 'CONFIRMED' | 'UNPAID' } {
    return ({
        ...b,
        status: b.status || confirmStatus(b)
    });
}

Although this is not a generic solution.
```

**Approach 2: Using Utility Type `Complete<T>` (Reference: "[TypeScript: Transforming optional properties to required properties that may be undefined](https://medium.com/terria/typescript-transforming-optional-properties-to-required-properties-that-may-be-undefined-7482cb4e1585)")**

If you eventually require **all** properties to be required, you can also take this approach (read article for more information):

```
type Complete<T> = {
    [P in keyof Required<T>]: Pick<T, P> extends Required<Pick<T, P>> ? T[P] : (T[P] | undefined);
}

function polyfillBidWithAmount(b: Bid) : Complete<Bid> {
    return ({
        ...b,
        status: b.status || confirmStatus(b)
    });
}
```